# read-only database + local changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have database located on a remote server, every so often I make a dump that I copy to my local server. During my work I make changes to this local copy. I would like to keep these changes when I reload the database from the remote server.

One option I have been thinking of is to have two databases (local_xyz and remote_xyz) with the same tables. The data from the remote server is loaded into remote_xyz and is set to be read-only. All updates and new data is written into local_xyz. Selects are executed on both databases and a union is done of local_xyz and remote_xyz.

This seems a complex solution and requires me to change all queries to have the union. I was hoping that there is another way to accomplish this. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: What will you do if somebody updates a row that you have already updated on your local copy? Whose changes do you want to see?

Comment: Good question, this will be up to the end user of the application. Right now I am leaning towards still keeping the local copy, however each of the rows have a timestamp of last update so that could be used as well.

Comment: You are asking us to design a database replication and merge system for you. This is an incredibly complex task, and any completed design will be full of countless trade-offs. There is no possible way we can answer your question. There's not even any possible way a book could answer your question. Only you, and your design team, can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a quick POC using a view that might help you. You have to change all your `select` statements to hit `local_merge`, and your `insert` and `update` statements must hit `local_changes` (although you're probably doing that already).

```
create table remote (
    id serial primary key,
    val varchar(20),
    update_ts timestamp
);

create table local_changes (
    id integer primary key,
    val varchar(20),
    update_ts timestamp
);

insert into remote (val, update_ts) values ('Hello', current_timestamp);
insert into remote (val, update_ts) values ('Hello, Europe', current_timestamp);
insert into local_changes values (2, 'Hello, World!', current_timestamp);

create or replace view local_merge as
select remote.id, 
   case 
       when remote.update_ts > local_changes.update_ts 
           or local_changes.update_ts is null
           then remote.val
       else local_changes.val
   end as val,
   case 
       when remote.update_ts > local_changes.update_ts 
           or local_changes.update_ts is null
           then remote.update_ts
       else local_changes.update_ts
   end as update_ts
from remote left join local_changes
on remote.id = local_changes.id
;

-- example select
select * from local_merge where id = 2;
```